# Problem with DNS setup on vps

Tags: dns

I got a strange message from my server today:

["The hostname (vps.listgiants.com) resolves to . It should resolve to 69.36.94.251. Please be sure to correct /etc/hosts as well as the 'A' entry in zone file for the domain.

Some are all of these problems can be caused by /etc/resolv.conf being setup incorrectly. Please check this file if you believe everything else is correct.

You may be able to automatically correct this problem by using the 'Add an A entry for your hostname' option under 'Dns Functions' in your Web Host Manager."]

I have not made any changes to the DNS and my hosting company is completely hands off so they cannot help me. I have an A entry as 69.36.94.251 as they recommend. resolv.conf is as it should be as well. Another problem is that my domain, listgiants.com points to another vps I own: 69.36.87.254. What else can I try to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no A records for vps in the listgiants.com dns settings.

[image]

Comment: How did you find that information?

Comment: [There are numerous](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&ie=UTF-8&q=dns+health) DNS health check services.  All the information has to be public or DNS wouldn't work.